# Bootstrap 3 - jerky scroll in Chrome

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, performance-testing

and I've edited fair amount of CSS, and when I tred to test it in Chrome, I've noticed when I click on the upper left link and try to scroll down, instead of scrolling I get this weird wobble-jerky effect.

I thought I did something wrong in my coding so I went back to the original template in the download directory and on the template's website live preview, and it still displays the same error.

You can see it in live preview here (it's faster than me posting jsfiddle link) -  [bootstrap freelance tempalte](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/)

Click on the upper left link and try to scroll down, you should see the error. In Firefox the website doesn't move or wobble, it stays "frozen" as you scroll the mousewheel down. The problem disappears when you scroll again for the second time.

How do I get rid of it, is there a way to identify what's causing it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the script below (with the code below it).

When you click on that link, the `.animate()` function is executing for 1.5 seconds to automatically scroll to the top of the page, even if you are already at the top of the page. So after clicking the link JavaScript is scrolling up while you are trying to scroll down which gives you that jerky effect.

Removing this code will resolve the issue, but then you will loose the nice easing page scrolling functionality.

I'm sure there is a way to stop the `.animate()` function as soon as you hit the top of the page, but I'm not sure exactly the best way to do that... maybe someone else can help with that part.

This is one of those classic "Its a feature, not a bug" scenarios.

`<script src="js/freelancer.js"></script>`

```
// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```